# Find and return a new column with unique values comparing two table columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables, one table for projects and other with services performed. This services always use a project number, but some projects aren't used yet.

Example table projects:

| Project Number | Object |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | describe one |
| 45146 | describe two |
| 10015 | describe three |

Example table services performed

| Location | Price | Project Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City 1 | 100,000 | 80002 |
| City 2 | 200,000 | 12345 |
| City 3 | 300,000 | 56874 |

I want to know (create a column) with the projects that weren't used yet. At this example, I need a column with 2 lines, project 45146 and 10015. How can I do it?

I'm still learning dax and I thought in SEARCH/FIND, but I didn't get what I need.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure Returns True/False values. You can use it as a measure for matrix or as a calculated column.

```
= 
ISEMPTY(
    EXCEPT(
        CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Projects[Project Number]))
        ,VALUES(performed[Project Number])
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you just add a new table and use `EXCEPT` for this?

```
Table = 
    EXCEPT ( 
        DISTINCT ( 'projects'[Project Number] ) , 
        DISTINCT ( 'services'[Project Number] ) 
    )
```

Not sure what this is solving, but if you specifically want to calculate this as a new column (/table) then by all means!